# Use Node packages in Phonegap/Cordova projects

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, node-modules

Is there a way to use Node modules within your phonegap/cordova app? I need to use Oauth and disconnect packages. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

How about [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)?
It may not work with the two modules that you need.

For OAuth there's [tips out there](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/oauth-with-phonegaps-inappbrowser-expiration-and-revocation.html), for the Discogs API I'm not so sure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried broswerify already. But since both packages are using some node platform-specify packages it didnt work. But i cant uderstand why ajax request doesnt work on this OAuth api.